# Mount multiple buckets on Ubuntu server, how to configure multiple access keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have followed [WhiteBoard Coder: Install and set up s3fs in Ubuntu 16.04 to mount an s3 bucket](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2017/12/how-to-mount-s3-bucket-as-hard-drive.html) to mount an S3 bucket on Ubuntu server.

Now what I want to do is to mount a second bucket on the same Ubuntu server... I have 2 different users, for each of these buckets, I don't know how to configure their passwords.

Previously I had to put the `access-key:secrect-key` in `/etc/passwd-s3fs` file, but now that I have 2 different set of tokens, I am not sure what to do?

### Update

**some background:** I am working on an e-commerce solution... I am working on an integration system with different clients who send their product info to our e-commerce via FTP.

As an example, client-1 is a car dealer who uploads hundreds of photos via FTP, to our FTP server... we have created an S3 bucket for client-1, mounted the bucket using S3FS and the photos directly go to the bucket...

Now I am getting data from a different car dealer, and due to security reasons, we want separate buckets and credentials for each clients, that's why I want to configure S3FS to work with separate Access-key fies.

Comment: Do you have admin access to IAM console?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: thanks for your comment... I have configured an FTP server (Ubuntu) which writes to S3 bucket, are you able to recommend a better alternative?

Comment: @ozlevka: yes I do

Comment: Amazon S3 should be accessed via its API. `s3fs` presents itself as a filesystem, but actually calls the Amazon S3 APIs. It would be best if your program directly called those APIs. See: [Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/s3/?id=docs_gateway)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: thanks for this... so I don't have a program...  The Ubuntu is set up as an FTP server. I have 1 client which uploads photos to his own S3 bucket via FTP and using S3FS... now I have got a new client and I want to use a different bucket/permission for the second client.

Comment: Could you expand upon your use-case? Are these 'clients' customers of yours? Do they send _you_ files, or do you send _them_ files? If Client 1 has an S3 bucket, why do they use FTP? It would be easier to upload directly to S3 or use a product like CyberDuck.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I have updated the question, hope it makes it clear.

Comment: Did the clients specifically request to use FTP? How are they uploading -- are they using an automated process, an interactive terminal session or an upload tool? Would you consider using a different upload method?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I am not entirely sure about their process, but it is automated and  one of them uses FileZilla, I am flexible and can change my process but don't have any control over the client's process.

Comment: FileZilla can upload directly to S3, which can avoid using FTP. The automated process can possibly be changed to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). FTP is an antiquated technology and it would be easier & cheaper for you to remove it from your workflow. Plus, it would solve your credentials problem because you could give each customer a set of credentials for them to upload directly to their Amazon s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s3fs accepts a flag to override the default password path:

> -o passwd_file (default="")
>
> specify  the  path  to  the  password  file,  which  which  takes  precedence  over  the  password  in $HOME/.passwd-s3fs and /etc/passwd-s3fs

Thus you should create two password files and provide a different path to each s3fs instance.

Answer (score 1):

Next words is my opinion only. We not discuss on performance and access issues and just try to solve your problem directly.

I would [create new policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html) that have access to both of buckets.

Next step [create group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups_create.html) that has this policy as permission.

Next step [add both of users to previous created group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups_manage_add-remove-users.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, but each bucket belongs to a different client, that's why I want to have separate access token for each bucket.

Comment: What you ftp server? What about run different ftp servers?

Comment: that would work, but it would be very expensive to set up a new server for each new client.

Comment: What you ftp server software? Can you define different end points to access of each user? And separate mounts by linux permissions?